# Getting No such file or directory [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_9137] error

Tags: file, keras, deep-learning

This may be a simple answer, but currently making a neural network using keras and I ran into this problem through this code

```
\`EPOCHS = 50

callbacks = \[
tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(

monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='min', min_delta=0.0001),
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
'weights.tf', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True),
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=15, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

\]

history = model.fit(
train_ds,
validation_data=val_ds,
verbose=1,
callbacks=callbacks,
epochs=EPOCHS,

)

model.load_weights('weights.tf')

model.evaluate(val_ds)\`
```

Output:

```
`Epoch 1/50


 NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 \<ipython-input-15-265d39d703c7\> in \<module\>
 10 \]
 11
 \---\> 12 history = model.fit(
 13     train_ds,
 14     validation_data=val_ds,

 1 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in         quick_execute(op_name,   num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
 52   try:
 53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
 \---\> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx.\_handle, device_name, op_name,
 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
 56   except core.\_NotOkStatusException as e:

 NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

 train/60377.jpg; No such file or directory
 \[\[{{node ReadFile}}\]\]
 \[\[IteratorGetNext\]\] \[Op:\__inference_train_function_9137\]
```

`
Here's my data:

[FairFace Dataset from Kaggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgLgf.png)

Here's how I preprocessed (through code I borrowed) the images from the FairFace dataset.

```
\`IMG_SIZE = 224
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
BATCH_SIZE = 224
NUM_CLASSES = len(labels_map)

# Dataset creation

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train.race, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, dtype='float32')
y_val = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(val.race, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, dtype='float32')

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.file, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train))
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val.file, y_val))

assert len(train_ds) == len(train.file) == len(train.race)
assert len(val_ds) == len(val.file) == len(val.race)

# Read files

def map_fn(path, label):
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))
image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
return image, label

# Read files

train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda path, lbl: (tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path)), lbl),      num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda path, lbl: (tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path)), lbl),      num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

# Batch and resize after batch, then prefetch

train_ds = val_ds.map(lambda imgs, lbls: (tf.image.resize(imgs, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)), lbls),    num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda imgs, lbls: (tf.image.resize(imgs, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)), lbls), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_ds = val_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

# Performance enchancement - cache, batch, prefetch

train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) 
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)\`
```

I tried changing the jpg file name but to no avail.